# How to make a custom collection select input with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-many-through

I would like to build a custom collection select input that takes a collection of text fields as input rather than a collection of check boxes. I have three basic models:

```
class Signature
  has_many :signature_terms
  has_many :signatures, :through => :signature_terms
  ...

class SignatureTerm
  attr_accessible :initial # user provides initial as verification

  belongs_to :signature
  belongs_to :term
  ...

class Term
  has_many :signature_terms
  has_many :signatures, :through => :signature_terms
  ...
```

I need to present every term for the user to initial. With radio buttons or check boxes, this is fairly easy to accomplish:

```
= simple_form_for @signature do |f|
  ...
  = f.collection_check_boxes :policy_term_signature_ids, @signature.terms, :id, :name
```

Which allows me to establish the relationship. However, I would like to present the user with every term for them to initial/not initial.

I've read the documentation on customizing simple form field inputs and have had success following the examples out of the code. What I haven't been able to do is implement a custom collection_select input. If someone could point me to an tutorial or functioning example, I'd sure appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the best approach but I would use the checkbox solution you currently have and then show a list of the choosen terms and textfields besides them for the initials.
Creating the list and textfields with JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After thinking about the problem a little more, I think the correct approach is to build all instances of the child relationship and then edit the children through fields_for. Though simple form provides a checkbox functionality, I think it's an exception to the "rails way."